# Entity Framework Code First - Can an existing table be mapped and made read only?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I need to use the users table from a parent site, is it possible to map the user table using the fluent API and have it be read only?

Answer (score 3):

In case of EF code first you can't directly make it "read-only" but you can design your code to not expose `DbContext` and related `DbSet` outside of your DAL logic so rest of the application cannot add a new user.

In case of EDMX based mapping you can make it read only by mapping it as a custom SQL query (or database view) where insert, update and delete operations are not supported until you map them custom SQL commands or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [comment on ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx#7569562), no.

> Right now we don’t support read-only (or semi-read-only) properties in
>   Code First but this is an interesting suggestion that I will talk with
>   our design team about. In general the Entity Framework doesn’t have
>   support for marking something as “read-only” so we may have to wait
>   for another major .NET framework release to get this working. For now,
>   you will have to add business logic in your entity to allow the
>   property to be set only once.
>
> Jeff Derstadt
>
> Entity Framework Code First Team